# Rust: nested values within struct

Tags: rust

I want to understand how to properly nest key/pair values within a struct. My use case is to create a type to return serialized JSON on my API responses.

I'm using rocket, this is my general setup:

```
// cargo.toml
[package]
name = "api"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.1", features = ["json"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
```

```rust
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;
use rocket::serde::json::Json;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

// ...

#[rocket::main]
async fn main() -> () {
  rocket::build().mount("/api/v1/", routes![single, collection,]).launch().await;

  ()
}
```

The idea is to have a wrapper type that can respond using kinda [json:api](https://jsonapi.org/) structure with a single value:

```json
{
  "links": {
    "self": "localhost:8000/users/user-one"
  },
  "data": {
    "type": "user",
    "id": "user-one",
    "session": {
      "self": "localhost:8000/users/user-one"
    },
    "attributes": {
      "id": "user-one",
      "name": "User one"
    },
  },
}
```

Or a collection of values:

```json
{
  "status": 200,
  "message": "Ok",
  "links": {
    "self": "localhost:8000/users"
  },
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "user",
      "id": "user-two",
      "session": {
        "self": "localhost:8000/users/user-two"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "id": "user-two",
        "name": "User two"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "user",
      "id": "user-three",
      "session": {
        "self": "localhost:8000/users/user-three"
      },
      "attributes": {
        "id": "user-three",
        "name": "User three"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

To achieve this I need to build some kind of `ApiResponse` type that will hold is main keys —`status`, `message`— and the nested ones —`links` and `values`—.
There is a catch though: the `values` property can be either a single value or a collection of values.

I build the `ApiResponse` this way, aiming to reuse it.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Links {
  self_url: Option<String>,
  next_url: Option<String>,
  previous_url: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Session {
  self_session: String,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Value<T> {
  value_type: String,
  id: String,
  session: Option<Session>,
  attributes: T,
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)] // Get rid of enum tag name
enum DataVariants<T> {
  Single(T),
  Collection(Vec<T>),
}

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct ApiResponse<T> {
  status: u8,
  message: String,
  links: Option<Links>,
  data: DataVariants<T>,
}
```

Then, in Rocket, I build my handlers as follows.

For a single value:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct User {
  id: String,
  name: String,
}

#[get("/single")]
pub async fn single() -> Json<ApiResponse<Value<User>>> {
  let user_1 = User {
    id: String::from("user-one"),
    name: String::from("User one"),
  };
  let data_user_1 = Value {
    value_type: "user".to_owned(),
    id: user_1.id.to_owned(),
    session: None,
    attributes: user_1,
  };

  let response_with_single_value = ApiResponse {
    status: 200,
    message: "Ok".to_owned(),
    links: None,
    data: DataVariants::Single(data_user_1),
  };

  return Json(response_with_single_value);
}
```

For a collection:

```rust
#[get("/collection")]
pub async fn collection() -> Json<ApiResponse<Value<User>>> {
  let user_2 = User {
    id: String::from("user-two"),
    name: String::from("User two"),
  };
  let data_user_2 = Value {
    value_type: "user".to_owned(),
    id: user_2.id.to_owned(),
    session: None,
    attributes: user_2,
  };

  let user_3 = User {
    id: String::from("user-three"),
    name: String::from("User three"),
  };
  let data_user_3 = Value {
    value_type: "user".to_owned(),
    id: user_3.id.to_owned(),
    session: None,
    attributes: user_3,
  };
  let response_with_collection = ApiResponse {
    status: 200,
    message: "Ok".to_owned(),
    links: None,
    data: DataVariants::Collection(vec![data_user_2, data_user_3]),
  };

  return Json(response_with_collection);
}
```

It works, here the responses.
For a single value:

```json
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Ok",
    "links": null,
    "data": {
        "value_type": "user",
        "id": "user-one",
        "session": null,
        "attributes": {
            "id": "user-one",
            "name": "User one"
        }
    }
}
```

For a collection:

```json
{
    "status": 200,
    "message": "Ok",
    "links": null,
    "data": [
        {
            "value_type": "user",
            "id": "user-two",
            "session": null,
            "attributes": {
                "id": "user-two",
                "name": "User two"
            }
        },
        {
            "value_type": "user",
            "id": "user-three",
            "session": null,
            "attributes": {
                "id": "user-three",
                "name": "User three"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't know if the way of structuring my `ApiResponse` struct with nested elements is correct, efficient or if follows the common practices: as it is now is quite verbose.

Any help will be welcome!